# First addCommand() item in a Form fails when used with native theme

Tags: java, codenameone

I have encountered a problem when using the the `addCommand()` method of the Form class along with the Native theme - other themes work fine.  See the following example:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));

// with native theme - can't click on the first command in the list
hi.addCommand(new Command("Dummy1") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        Dialog.show("Dummy1 Clicked!", "You clicked the Dummy1", "OK", null);
    }
});
hi.addCommand(new Command("Dummy2") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        Dialog.show("Dummy2 Clicked!", "You clicked the Dummy2", "OK", null);
    }
});
hi.show();
```

When I create an application using the code above, a click on the second command ("Dummy2") produces the expected Dialog, but a click on the first command ("Dummy1") does nothing.

This only happens when using the Native theme.  If I switch to Flat Blue, then clicking on either command produces the expected Dialog.

This behavior happens both on the Simulator and on a real Android device (don't know about iOS).

Fyi, my toolchain is NetBeans IDE v8.2, Java 1.8.0_25, with the CodenameOne plugin v3.6.0.

Has anyone else seen this?  Am I missing something?  If so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried styling the `SideCommand` but it didn't seem to help. What worked for me was to define a style for `TitleArea` and simply uncheck `Derived` for the `Padding` settings (I left them all set to 0px).

I have no idea why this works - I would have thought that the derived values would have been zero in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is very narrow and very close to the top the click might be misinterpreted as a click out of bounds or on the status bar area. You need to set the styling of the `SideCommand` to have a sensible default as this element is very application specific. Otherwise touches might be lost.